# How do I handle exceptions on Python Social Auth

Tags: python, django, authentication

How do I handle this kind of exception `AuthAlreadyAssociated` on `Python Social Auth`?

All the answers I found are for `Django Social Auth` but it seems plenty has changed ever since they were written.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a new middleware in your app's `middleware.py`:

```
from social_django.middleware import SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware
from social_core import exceptions as social_exceptions     
from django.http import HttpResponse

class MySocialAuthExceptionMiddleware(SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if hasattr(social_exceptions, exception.__class__.__name__):
            # Here you can handle the exception as you wish
            return HttpResponse("Exception %s while processing your social account." % exception)
        else:
            return super(MySocialAuthExceptionMiddleware, self).process_exception(request, exception)
```

and add its path to `settings.py`

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'path.to.MySocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
   )
```

Comment: if suppose the problem in some place but it will raise here ..

Comment: Use the following example if you want to explicitly handle the AuthAlreadyAssociated exception. ```if isinstance(exception, social_exceptions.AuthAlreadyAssociated):```. And redirect for instance: ```return redirect(reverse('index'))```.