# What is the right way of handling python-social-auth exceptions when using Flask?

Tags: python, flask, python-social-auth

I'm adding PSU to a Flask app and all is going pretty well so far, but I can't figure out how to handle the exceptions raised by PSU. One such exception is social.exceptions.AuthCanceled, raised when a user decides to cancel the auth process. I would obviously want to catch that and display some message.

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305986/how-do-i-handle-exceptions-on-python-social-auth) on how to do this in Django by creating a new Middleware. However, that approach seems to use middleware.py defined only in PSU's django_app (and not in the flask_app).

I have some experience with Flask but haven't added Middleware before, and I'm not sure this is the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Try defining an `errorhandler` (docs at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.errorhandler), like this:

```
@app.errorhandler(500)  # since exceptions will produce 500 errors
def error_handler(error):
    if isinstance(error, SocialAuthBaseException):
        return redirect('/error')
```

**The solution below this line won't work**

---

Try with a `teardown_request` (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/reqcontext/#teardown-callbacks), like this

```
@app.teardown_request
def teardown_handler(exception=None):
    if exception and isinstance(exception, SocialAuthBaseException):
        return redirect('/error')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried it out, it gets inside the `if` but seems to ignore the `return`. Apparently `teardown_request` functions _are not allowed to modify the request, and their return values are ignored_ (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.teardown_request).

Comment: The updated approach works like a charm. For others implementing this, don't forget to set `DEBUG = False` and `TEST = False` in your config to test this, otherwise the exception in displayed and the error handler never called. Also note you can't `flash` within the error handler, but you can of course redirect to a page that does.

Comment: I've added a section about it in the docs http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/configuration/flask.html#exceptions-handling

Comment: Sounds good, thanks for following up and for the very useful app!